# How to make NSIS RMDir operate on subdirectories?

Tags: nsis

In an NSIS installer script I have:

```
RMDir "$INSTDIR"
```

Now, if the user sets the installation directory to `C:\Program Files\Product`, it works fine, however if they install to something deeper, such as `C:\Program Files\Company\Product` for example, RMDir gets rid of "Product" but not "Company". How can I make it delete each empty directory down to the root (WITHOUT using /r)... e.g. delete Product if empty, delete Company if empty, delete Program Files if empty, and so on?

---

EDIT: The function I ended up using:

```
# Delete empty directories recursively
var deleteDir
var dirLength
Function un.PathDeleteEmptyDirRecurse
ClearErrors
loop:
    Sleep 50 ; Without a small delay here, the directory sometimes won't get removed
    RMDir "$deleteDir" ; Remove the directory
    IfErrors end
    strlen $dirLength $deleteDir ; Store the length of the path
    intcmp $dirLength 3 end end ; If the length of the path is <= 3 (e.g. C:\), we're at the root drive
    GetFullPathName $deleteDir "$deleteDir\.." ; <path>\.. results in the parent directory of <path>
    IfErrors end loop
end:
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want this in the uninstaller and not the installer:

```
Function un.PathDeleteEmptyDirRecurse 
exch $0
push $1
ClearErrors
loop:
RMDir $0
IfErrors end
strlen $1 $0
intcmp $1 3 end end ;root of drive?
GetFullPathName $0 "$0\.."
IfErrors end loop
end:
pop $1
pop $0
FunctionEnd

...

push $instdir
call un.PathDeleteEmptyDirRecurse
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great except for one thing: how do I call it twice in a row? `push $instdir1 \ call un.PathDeleteEmptyDirRecurse \ push $instdir2 \ call un.PathDeleteEmptyDirRecurse` (using \ to simulate newline) does not work.

Comment: @Jake Petroules: Works fine when I try: http://nsis.pastebin.com/5JgDwcEH (You must start at the _deepest_ folder in the tree)

Comment: I am starting at the deepest folder... quite puzzling. This is what I have in my NSIS script: http://nsis.pastebin.com/1scSjsgM

Comment: I added a call to ClearErrors in my answer, I'm thinking that is the problem

Comment: Apparently not. However something very strange is that if I add a `MessageBox MB_OK "$0"` command just before RMDir, deletion of the directory works. It also shows that it's getting to delete the folder I want (e.g. the message box shows C:\path\to\the\folder\), but RMDir simply doesn't operate.

Comment: Maybe the folder is locked by explorer or anti-virus, try Process Monitor from Sysinternals and see if it provides any clues

Comment: It appears the issue is that `!insertmacro MUI_STARTMENU_GETFOLDER Application $StartMenuFolder` isn't working as expected; returning the default start menu path, not what the user entered. As your solution was correct for the question I've accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use;

```
Function un.RMDirUP
  !define RMDirUP '!insertmacro RMDirUPCall'
  !macro RMDirUPCall _PATH
      push '${_PATH}'
      Call un.RMDirUP
  !macroend

  ; $0 - current folder
  ClearErrors
  Exch $0
  RMDir "$0\.."
  IfErrors Skip
  ${RMDirUP} "$0\.."
  Skip:
  Pop $0
FunctionEnd
```

This let's you call it in the uninstall with 
`${RMDirUP} "$INSTDIR"`

Comment: As far as I know, this does not work correctly, if the function bubbles up to the root directory (i.e. "C:\"). My uninstallers always crash in that case ...

Answer (score -2):

I finally ended up using just these two lines to delete **everything** in the installation directory and the directory itself (if empty):

```
RMDir /r "$INSTDIR"
RMDir "$INSTDIR\..\."
```

Comment: This is very dangerous. What happens if your user chose to install to c:\ or c:\program files\? You've just removed all files and subdirectories in that folder.